# Forwarding www. not working

Tags: godaddy, domain-forwarding

I am using GoDaddy to forward my url to a url of my choice and whenever I enter the domain eg. name.com I am accordingly forwarded but when I use www.name.com it shows the following:

> This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.

Anyone aware of any solutions?

Comment: Mistake 1. using GoDaddy DNS to do the redirect. Consider using server-side redirects.